# Entity Framework Update Not Firing. Weirdness abound

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm reasonably comfortable with using EF and most of my stuff "just works". Unfortunately, I've come across a real conundrum with a simple update. I *think* it may be a type problem, but I wanted to see if anyone else had some opinions.

This is the code in question:-

```
using (var ctx = new jetsetrEntities())
    {
        var teddies = ctx.Teddies.First(i => i.Code == metric.Teddy);

        _log.Info("Teddies entertainment direct from data", teddies.Entertainment);

        teddies.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        teddies.Entertainment = Convert.ToDecimal(entertainment);

        _log.Info("Now, has it changed?", teddies.Entertainment);           

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        _log.Info("After the save...", teddies.Entertainment);
    }
}
```

Log output shows that `var teddies` works correctly and returns `teddies.Entertainment` value, in this case a `0.00`.  Then I attempt to set the values of the object context - converting the decimal to ints, just in case.

Yet now, `teddies.Entertainment` is empty/null and `ctx.SaveChanges();` doesn't actually do anything. There are no errors, but from the logs I can see something strange is happening and the database is not updating.

Can anyone point out my stupidity?

Help, as always, is appreciated.

Chris

**EDIT 1**

Thank you @Killingsworth and @Gert Arnold. I added a `try/catch` and typed the `entertainment` and `value` variables as decimal, like so:-

```
try
{
    using (var ctx = new jetsetrEntities())
    {
        var teddy = ctx.Teddies.First(i => i.Code == metric.Teddy);

        _log.Info("[1] teddy with entertainment={0}", teddy.Entertainment);

        teddy.Value = value;
        teddy.Entertainment = entertainment;

        _log.Info("[2] Now, has it changed? {0}", teddy.Entertainment);

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        _log.Info("[3] After the save... {0}", teddy.Entertainment);
    }
} 
catch(Exception exception)
{
    _log.Info("Exception occured {0}", exception.Message);
}
```

I get no exception, and `teddy.Entertainment` is output in the logs as "31" in this case. Where is the decimal places I wonder? "31.00"?. Unfortunately, the data is still not saved to the db.

Comment: What is the type of `teddies.Entertainment` field? And what does `Convert.ToDecimal(entertainment)` return?

Comment: teddies is really only 1 teddy, just kind of misleading

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in a try/catch(EntityCommandExecutionException e) to see if the SaveChanges() executed correctly?

Comment: @Andrei 'teddies.Entertainment' is decimal.

Comment: @Killingsworth I'll try just that and report back...

Comment: @dooburt, then how can it be `null/empty`?

Comment: What if you just assign a decimal value (without `Convert.ToDecimal`)?

Comment: @GertArnold as you and Killingsworth have suggested I've changed the code - no luck.  Please see the edit above... Any ideas?

Comment: SaveChanges() returns an int that is the number of records saved. It's probably returning 0 from what you've described, but it's another thing you could check.

Comment: @Steve I'll add the code to check that and report back... thanks ;)

Comment: Also, step through with the debugger (or log) the value of `teddy.EntityState`. It should change from `Unchanged` to `Modified` when you change one of its properties. Edit - You might have to call `GetObjectStateEntry` followed by looking at the result of that call's `State` property.

Comment: @Steve just added `var affected = ctx.SaveChanges();`. It returns a `1`. Yet the database remains unaffected... I'm checking I haven't got my databases mixed up (ut oh)...

Comment: @Steve nope, it's the right database. But it is not saving. I'm utterly baffled!

Comment: Are you able to create and add a brand new entity? If that says it saves it, but it doesn't appear in your database, I think you've got some other problem...

Comment: @Steve problem solved! Unbelievable calamity on my part. After `teddies` was apparently saved in the first instance (and it was and always was), later on up the chain I passed an empty `teddy` object to be saved for another purpose. Sloppy code = stupid errors. Steve, thanks so much - please add an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I don't think I answered your question really. Post your own answer and accept your own :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable calamity on my part. After teddies was apparently saved in the first instance (and it was and always was), later on up the chain I passed an empty teddy object to be saved for another purpose. Sloppy code = stupid errors. Steve, thanks so much - please add an answer and I'll mark it as correc